# How to fix: Navbar styling issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

The following is the code for the navbar on https://www.vimaldevelopers.com/vimalproject0/residential-projects-mumbai/vimalprojects.html

Checked the bootstrap version on the bad navbar page and it is 3.3.7

```
<div class="col-lg-9 col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 toll-col-mob">
    <div style="background: #85B540!important; width: 95rem; height: 2rem; ">
        <div class="hotlines text-white">Contact No.
            <a href="#" class="toll-no">0222-8981111</a>
            <!-- <a href="tel:1 800 212 8888" class="toll-no">1 800 212 8888</a> -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="background: #18191b!important; padding-top: 15px">
        <nav class="toplinks">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="">Vimal Developers</a></li>

                <li class="drop-drown-menu clearfix">
                    <a href="omkar-1973-worli#" class="active">projects</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-content menu-show">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="">Residential</a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="">Commercial</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li><a href="#" class="">Contact Us</a></li>


            </ul>
        </nav>
```

I want to make it look like the main page on https://www.vimaldevelopers.com. This page is using v4.

This is what the above code looks like (the bad navbar) :
[image: img1]

This is how I want it to look like :
[image: img2]

Someone please save my day!

Comment: As per your code for large screen your using only 9 columns `col-lg-9 col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-12`. How is it going to occupy entire screen.

Comment: Updated the code on [link](https://www.vimaldevelopers.com/vimalproject0/residential-projects-mumbai/vimalprojects.html) The green colored navbar is still not covering the whole width :( removed the col part and tried width 100% instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]try this :::

```
.toll-col-mob {
    width:100%;
}
.toplinks ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! I added the code and it worked. Will make it live in a while. Do you know how I can solve the disappearance of navbar <li> components when reducing screen size?

Comment: Refer this link ::: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_topnav

Answer (score 0):

U don't need navbar in column structure. Try with this code. Hope can help you.

```
 <body style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
  <div class="toll-col-mob">
    <div style="background: #85B540!important; height: 2rem; " >
      <div class="hotlines text-white">Contact No.
       <a href="#" class="toll-no">0222-8981111</a>
       <!-- <a href="tel:1 800 212 8888" class="toll-no">1 800 212 8888</a> -->
     </div>
   </div>
   <div style="background: #18191b!important; padding-top: 15px">
    <nav class="toplinks">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="">Vimal Developers</a></li>    /  

        <li class="drop-drown-menu clearfix">
          <a href="omkar-1973-worli#" class="active">projects</span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-content menu-show">
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="" >Residential</a>
            </li>

            <li>
              <a href="#" class="" >Commercial</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li> /
        <li><a href="#" class="">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul> 
    </nav>
  </body>
```

Comment: Updated the code on [link](https://www.vimaldevelopers.com/vimalproject0/residential-projects-mumbai/vimalprojects.html) The green colored navbar is still not covering the whole width :(

Answer (score 0):

I think in your second div "width" will be 100%

```
<div style="background: #85B540!important; width: 100%; height: auto;" >
```

and please explain little bit more if it doesn't work.

Comment: Updated the code on [link](https://www.vimaldevelopers.com/vimalproject0/residential-projects-mumbai/vimalprojects.html) The green colored navbar is still not covering the whole width :(

Comment: Tried the width 100% code as well but it doesn't make any changes

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
body{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
<div class="">
                <div style="background: #85B540!important; width: 100vw; height: 2rem" >
                <div class="hotlines text-white ">Call:
                 <a href="#" class="toll-no">0222-8981111</a>

                </div>
                </div>

                <div style="background: #18191b!important; padding-top: 15px">
                <nav class="toplinks">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" class="">Vimal Developers</a></li>    /  

                        <li class="drop-drown-menu clearfix">
                            <a href="omkar-1973-worli#" class="active">projects</span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-content menu-show">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#" class="" >Residential</a>
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <a href="#" class="" >Commercial</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li> /

                        <li><a href="#" class="">Contact Us</a></li>


                    </ul> 
                </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Updated the code on [link](https://www.vimaldevelopers.com/vimalproject0/residential-projects-mumbai/vimalprojects.html) The green colored navbar is still not covering the whole width :(

Comment: set width: 100vw and then check it